# not understanding stdout semantics

Tags: c, linux, redirect, cat

A newbie here!

My program below is trying to act like (a little) `cat` command in Linux.

1. if no arguments is supplied then it takes input from user and prints on screen.(input   buffer is assumed 10 for a very simple scenario)..
2. if i pass multiple arguments it is working..i.e. it is showing the contents of different files one by one -as programmed..

--now the point is that when i give command on shell like:

> ./mycat abc.txt > test

where `mycat` is my program name and `abc.txt` is the required file and i am redirecting it to a new file test.
Strange part which I am not able to understand is that after redirection if i look into the file test, it shows the data from the file `abc.txt` first then my printf functions in the c program instead of showing the printfs and THEN the data. What is the reason for this?

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char buf[10]; 
    int x,read_bytes,i,fd;
    read_bytes=1;
    char read_buf[1024*1024];

    for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
         printf("you entered  %s\n",argv[i]); //this printf

    switch(argc)
    {
    case 1:
         x=read(0,buf,sizeof(buf));
         write(1,buf,x);
         break;

    default:
         for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
         {
             printf("showing the %dth file\n\n",i);
             fd=open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
             if(fd==-1)
             {
                 perror("no file opened for such name");
                 exit(1);
             }
             while(read_bytes!=0)
             {
                 read_bytes=read(fd,read_buf,sizeof(read_buf));
                 if(read_bytes==-1)
                 {
                     perror("not able to read\n");
                     exit(2);
                 }
                 write(1,read_buf,read_bytes);
             }
             read_bytes=1;
             close(fd);
         }
         break;
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're using Posix `read`/`write` and not the more portable and easy-to-digest standard C `fread`/`fwrite`?

Comment: You should try to be less creative with your indentation.

Comment: Why "no file opened for such name"?  That is a particularly unhelpful error message.  Just do perror( argv[ i ]) and tell the user which file is problematic.

Comment: @kerrek SB- actually i want to know the "raw" and the "buffered" input output mechanisms,the time taken with different functions or sys calls,...

Comment: @saurabh: Oh OK. Did you notice any differences? Make sure to compile with maximal optimizations before you compare.

Comment: @kerrek SB- sir, can u plz. actually tell me the need for the fread/fwrite functions instead of using the read,write system calls??
even the read/write system calls are buffered(at userspace and at kernel space), then what is the difference?
(knowing the point that if we get the data in larger chunks, performance is better in case of system calls)
and also,
in "Linux Programming Interface" chapter-13,by Micheal Kerrisk says that 
stdio functions such as fread, fwrite etc. are same too but they just fetches the data in larger chunks so as to reduce the system calls...
CONFUSED! I am:>

Comment: I thought as much. Well... `fread`/`fwrite` is C, and `read`/`write` are not. (They're only in Posix.) Do you need a better reason?

Comment: btw, sir, as almost all of the os are posix compliant(fully or partially),
so can i make programs using read/write POSIX sys calls..
and the problem will arise only in the case of NON-POSIX compliant os...am i right sir?

Answer (score 4):

`printf` also prints to `stdout`, whose file descriptor is `1`, so you're writing the `printf` line to the same output as the file contents.

You might prefer writing diagnostics to a separate output, such as `stderr`:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Hello world.\n");
```

Comment: +1 Just to add something to your question, you can also redirect both stdout and stderr with >&

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are correct, but don't seem to explain the problem.
Both `printf` and `write(1)` write to stdout. But `printf` is buffered, while `write` isn't.
So data you write with `printf` goes first to some buffer, and is really written only when the OS chooses to. Data written by `write`, however, goes directly to the file.
The result is that everything is printed, but not in the order you want. Data printed by `printf` can be written after data written by a later `write`.

Comment: so sir, can i say::that write system call  uses raw output method..
it bypass the kernel buffer and directly writes to stdout.???

Comment: `write` goes directly to the kernel. `printf` uses a buffer (not in kernel, but in userspace) before going to the kernel also.

Comment: @ugoren- as what i have studied, I gt to know that there are two buffer one in userspace and one in kernel space, 
as soon as a call write system call is made, the data is transferred from user space to kernel space buffer only*..
and at other moment the data from the kernel buffer is written to the file(OS specific), thats why the system calls are not synchronised sometimes(unless we specify)

Comment: and

"printf uses a buffer(not in kernel, but in userspace)"
so sir, considering this and looking at my problem simultaneously,, I am not able to justify the cause of error in my program as write system call also starts from the user space..

Answer (score 1):

Please use `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf` so that stdout buffer is flushed. After doing this printfs will be shown in order as per the code.

Here's modified code.

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char buf[10]; 
    int x,read_bytes,i,fd;
    read_bytes=1;
    char read_buf[1024*1024];

    for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
        printf("you entered  %s\n",argv[i]); //this printf
    fflush(stdout);
    switch(argc)
    {
     case 1:
          x=read(0,buf,sizeof(buf));
          write(1,buf,x);
          break;

     default:
          for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
          {
              printf("showing the %dth file\n\n",i);
              fflush(stdout);
              fd=open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
              if(fd==-1)
              {
                 perror("no file opened for such name");
                 exit(1);
              }
              while(read_bytes!=0)
              {
                 read_bytes=read(fd,read_buf,sizeof(read_buf));
                 if(read_bytes==-1)
                 {
                     perror("not able to read\n");
                     exit(2);
                 }
                 write(1,read_buf,read_bytes);
             }
             read_bytes=1;
             close(fd);
         }
         break;
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: sir, i tried it but it is not working for my above mentioned case...i.e. for a syntax like this
./mycat wordlist.txt wordlist.txt > abc

Comment: thnx sir,, just gave a call to fflush() and it is working as you said...
bt can you explain the reason for the undetermined behaviour in case of absense of the fflush call.....